# How can I best extract transitions in a transactional table?

Tags: sql, mysql

Hypothetical example:

I have an SQL table that contains a billion or so transactions:

```
| Cost | DateTime   |
| 1.00 | 2009-01-02 |
| 2.00 | 2009-01-03 |
| 2.00 | 2009-01-04 |
| 3.00 | 2009-01-05 |
| 1.00 | 2009-01-06 |
...
```

What I want is to pair down the data so that I only see the cost *transitions*:

```
| Cost | DateTime   |
| 1.00 | 2009-01-02 |
| 2.00 | 2009-01-03 |
| 3.00 | 2009-01-05 |
| 1.00 | 2009-01-06 |
...
```

The simplest (and slowest) way to do this is to iterate over the entire table, tracking the changes.  Is there a faster/better way to do this in SQL?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand the problem completely. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: I think he's asking to find the points where the Cost changes. Notice that he skipped the second sequential 2.00 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no faster way. You could write a query that does the same job but it will be much slower. You (as a developer) know that you need to compare a value only with its direct previous value, and there is no way to specify this with SQL. So you can do optimizations that SQL cannot.
So I imagine the fastest is to write a program that streams the results from the disk, holding in RAM only the last valid value and the current one (filtering out every value that is equal to the last valid).

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of trying to use a sledge hammer when a hammer is needed. You want to extract some crazy reporting data out of a table but to do so is going to KILL your SQL Server. What you need to do to track changes is to create a tracking table specifically for this purpose. Then use a trigger that records a change in value in a product into this table. So on my products table, when I change the price it goes into the price tracking table.

If you are using this to track stock prices or something similar then again you use the same approach except you do a comparison of the price table and if a change occurs you save it. So the comparison only happens with new data, all the old comparisons are still housed in one location so you don't need to rerun the query which is going to kill your SQL Server's performance.

Comment: In fact, I'm writing migration code to port a system to a new architecture (and schema).  The original design didn't track such changes, so I'm playing catchup.  Thanks for the tips!